# PHP CURL Get request with uri containing dollar sign returns 400 Bad Request

Tags: php, rest, curl

I am trying to use the ChannelAdvisor REST API in PHP to load a list of stock levels that changed since the last sync. This process is documented here: http://developers.channeladvisor.com/rest/#946

Based on the documentation, I have ran a test in Post Man (chrome rest client) to make sure It's working as intended & it does:

[image]

Since the test was successfully, I started to work on the PHP script to interact with the REST API in the same manner and it's not quite working correctly. I am getting the following output:

> Bad Request - HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.

This is my script so far (I am working with Laravel 4, but it's unrelated to that). The issue is with the `curlGET` method:

```
<?php namespace Latheesan\ThirdParty\ChannelAdvisorREST;

class ChannelAdvisorREST {

    /**
     * ChannelAdvisor base uri
     */
    const BASE_URL = 'https://api.channeladvisor.com';

    /**
     * ChannelAdvisor config data
     */
    private $config;

    /**
     * Class constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->config = \Config::get('channeladvisor');
    }

    /**
     * Method to load stock updates since last sync.
     *
     * @param $accountId
     * @param $lastSync
     * @return array
     */
    public function getStockUpdates($accountId, $lastSync)
    {
        // Anticipate errors
        try
        {
            // Init
            $stockUpdates = [];

            // Query channel advisor
            $stockUpdateResults = self::curlGET($accountId, '/v1/Products?$filter=QuantityUpdateDateUtc gt '. $lastSync);

            // TODO: parse $stockUpdateResults into $stockUpdates

            // Success
            return $this->successResponse($stockUpdateResults);
        }
        catch (\Exception $ex)
        {
            // Error response
            return $this->errorResponse('Failed to load stock updates - '. $ex->getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Generic method to output error responses.
     *
     * @param string $message
     * @return array
     */
    private function errorResponse($message = '')
    {
        // Error
        return [
            'IsError' => true,
            'ErrorMsg' => $message,
            'Data' => ''
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Generic method to output success responses.
     *
     * @param $data
     * @return array
     */
    private function successResponse($data)
    {
        // Success
        return [
            'IsError' => false,
            'ErrorMsg' => '',
            'Data' => $data
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Method to get access token from rest server.
     *
     * @param $accountId
     * @return string
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    private function getAccessToken($accountId)
    {
        // Define cache key
        $cache_key = 'CA_REST_ACCESS_TOKEN.'. $accountId;

        // Check if there is a cached version of access token
        if (\Cache::has($cache_key))
            return \Cache::get($cache_key);

        // Anticipate errors
        try
        {
            // Call rest api server
            $response = self::curlPOST('/oauth2/token', [
                'client_id' => $this->config['api_app_id'],
                'grant_type' => 'soap',
                'scope' => 'inventory',
                'developer_key' => $this->config['api_developer_key'],
                'password' => $this->config['api_password'],
                'account_id' => $accountId
            ]);

            // Check if there was an error
            if (isset($response->Message))
                throw new \Exception($response->Message);
            if (isset($response->error))
                throw new \Exception($response->error);

            // Check if there was an invalid response
            if (!isset($response->access_token) || !isset($response->expires_in))
                throw new \Exception('Invalid response - '. json_encode($response));

            // Cache server response
            \Cache::add($cache_key, $response->access_token, floor($response->expires_in / 60));

            // Success
            return $response->access_token;
        }
        catch (\Exception $ex)
        {
            // Rethrow error
            throw new \Exception('Failed to load rest api access token - '. $ex->getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to generate a HTTP POST request
     *
     * @param $endpoint
     * @param array $fields
     * @return string
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    private function curlPOST($endpoint, $fields = array())
    {
        // Open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->config['api_app_id'] .':'. $this->config['api_shared_secret']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, self::BASE_URL . $endpoint);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields, '', '&'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        ));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        $verbose = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);

        // Execute post request
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        // Debug error
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            $curlError = 'Error #'. curl_errno($ch) .':'. htmlspecialchars(curl_error($ch));
            rewind($verbose);
            $verboseLog = stream_get_contents($verbose);
            $curlError .= "\r\nDebug Info: ". htmlspecialchars($verboseLog);
            curl_close($ch);
            throw new \Exception($curlError);
        }
        @fclose($verbose);

        // Close connection
        curl_close($ch);

        // Finished
        return json_decode($result);
    }

    /**
     * Method to generate HTTP GET request
     *
     * @param $accountId
     * @param $queryString
     * @return string
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    private function curlGET($accountId, $queryString)
    {
        // Open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        // Set the url, query string & access token
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, self::BASE_URL . $queryString);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Authorization: Bearer '. self::getAccessToken($accountId)
        ));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        $verbose = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);

        // Execute post request
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        // TESTING
        var_dump($result); exit;
        // TESTING

        // Debug error
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            $curlError = 'Error #'. curl_errno($ch) .':'. htmlspecialchars(curl_error($ch));
            rewind($verbose);
            $verboseLog = stream_get_contents($verbose);
            $curlError .= "\r\nDebug Info: ". htmlspecialchars($verboseLog);
            curl_close($ch);
            throw new \Exception($curlError);
        }
        @fclose($verbose);

        // Close connection
        curl_close($ch);

        // Finished
        return json_decode($result);
    }
}
```

The above is a façade class, so I use it like this:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r(ChannelAdvisorREST::getStockUpdates
(
    'xxx-xxx-xxx',              // accountId
    '2016-01-18T11:50:03.000Z'  // lastSync utc date & time
));
echo '</pre>';
```

Any idea why it works in Postman REST Client, but fails in my PHP? I thought I am doing the exact same steps. I tried `urlencode` the query string also; but that did not work either.

Comment: Postman generates the request for you if you want (in PHPCurl) by clicking the code sign. What does it generate?

Comment: Oh wow, that's pretty handy. Did not know it could do that. I am getting the following back: http://pastebin.com/r8KKQQbS (looks like the query string was urlencoded).

Comment: When I use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, self::BASE_URL . urlencode($queryString));`, the uri php generates looks like this: `https://api.channeladvisor.com%2Fv1%2FProducts%3F%24filter%3DQuantityUpdateDateUtc+gt+2016-01-18T11%3A50%3A03.000Z` which is different from the one postman generated: `https://api.channeladvisor.com/v1/Products?%24filter=QuantityUpdateDateUtc%20gt%202016-01-18T12%3A20%3A03.000` - so how is postman partially urlencoding? :s

Comment: Afraid not, the header is fine. Postman is just adding these two extra headers: `cache-control` and `postman-token` (which the channeladvisor rest api does not need). The issue appears to be with the way the request uri is being generated. See the way php urlencode result vs the way postman does it. In php `/` is getting encoded, not sure how to tell php to generate the url like postman does.

Comment: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests  `EncodeURIComponent` there is a difference between adding it in the url bar and in the key value thingy I believe. Please read the doc

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it (for now) like this and it's working correctly for me. Let me know if there's a better/proper way to do this.

```
/**
 * Method to generate HTTP GET request
 *
 * @param $accountId
 * @param $queryString
 * @return string
 * @throws \Exception
 */
private function curlGET($accountId, $queryString)
{
    // Open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set the url, query string & access token
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, self::BASE_URL . self::formatUri($queryString));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Authorization: Bearer '. self::getAccessToken($accountId)
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    $verbose = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);

    // Execute post request
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    // Debug error
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        $curlError = 'Error #'. curl_errno($ch) .':'. htmlspecialchars(curl_error($ch));
        rewind($verbose);
        $verboseLog = stream_get_contents($verbose);
        $curlError .= "\r\nDebug Info: ". htmlspecialchars($verboseLog);
        curl_close($ch);
        throw new \Exception($curlError);
    }
    @fclose($verbose);

    // Close connection
    curl_close($ch);

    // Finished
    return json_decode($result);
}

/**
 * Method to format query string
 *
 * @param $queryString
 * @return string
 */
private function formatUri($queryString)
{
    return str_replace(
        ['$', ' '],
        ['%24', '%20'],
        $queryString
    );
}
```